# Conditional operations in RxJava code

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava and often find myself resorting to solutions like the ones below for conditional operations. Here I want to chain two calls in sequence, and then return an int depending on what the outcome of the call chain is. Are there any "rxified" way to improve this code? (using blockingSingle here since I'm passing the resulting int to a legacy application to which I cannot push values as of yet)

```
return restApiAdapter.closePosition(request)
            .flatMap(dealReference -> restApiAdapter.getDealConfirmationObservable(dealReference.getValue())
                .map(dealConfirmationResponse -> {
                    if (dealConfirmationResponse.getDealStatus() == DealStatus.ACCEPTED) {
                        return SUCCESS.getValue();
                    } else {
                        return FAIL.getValue();
                    }
                })
            )
            .onErrorReturn(e -> ZorroReturnValues.BROKER_SELL_FAIL.getValue())
            .blockingSingle();
```

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code here, making it hard to see the important RxJava aspects that relate to your question.  Can you please dramatically simplify this?

Comment: wow that is a hell of a code :) - check SOLID principles and Clean Code guidelines.

Comment: Simplified example, clearer now? @andrei-macarie that was not what I was asking for

Comment: Ok that's a lot clearer now :)

Comment: Beyond using ?: or moving the if/else into a sensibly-named helper method, I can't think of anything that would significantly help that particular part of the code.

Comment: To use Rx the most and increase the semantics of your code, if possible, I would suggest analyzing which returned statuses pose error conditions. Then you can return from getDealConfirmationObservable() observables that emit errors (eg: for DealStatus others than ACCEPTED). Thus flexibility will be increased because the user of your API can handle different cases (eg: ignoring, retry, conditional, ...) by using [Rx error handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators).

Comment: @andrei-macarie Thanks, that's a great idea. I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

After moving the logic to check for ACCEPTED/REJECTED orders as suggested by @andrei-macarie, the code now looks more like this

```
return restApiAdapter.closePosition(request)
            .flatMap(dealReference -> restApiAdapter.getDealConfirmationObservable(dealReference.getValue())
                .map(dealConfirmationResponse -> SUCCESS.getValue()
            )
            .onErrorReturn(e -> FAIL.getValue())
            .blockingSingle();
```